# Why is this code to print the following zeros and ones pattern not working?

Tags: java

```
0                   
10                      
010             
1010                    
01010           
101010              
0101010
```

This is my code but I always print a 1 in the (i%2 != 0) part that is not needed. This is not related to number systems just a pattern to print.

```
public class Playground  {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j+=2) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.print(0);
                System.out.print(1);
            }
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j+=2) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(1);
                System.out.print(0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(j % 2);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Or you can do this (suggested by @MitchTalmadge) :

```
String output = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    output = (i % 2) + output;
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: You could also replace the if with just `System.out.print(j % 2);`

Comment: Yes, it would be better to do that in his case. editting my post. Thanks @thatotherguy

Comment: There's a much better way to do this. I can't post it however because the question is on hold.

Comment: @MitchTalmadge You know you can't post now, and believe me this post will remain on hold. But I am curious to know what do you think the better way to do this would be.

Comment: @afzalex This is my method: http://pastebin.com/TYNZBELm Whether or not it is "better" would have to be tested, but I feel like this method is a bit more understandable.

Comment: Yes it will be better to do that. editting my post. Thanks @MitchTalmadge